# How to find if two dots on a graph intersect

Tags: python, numpy, graphing

I'm working on a project where there are four turtles in the middle of a circle, and they each follow a random path until one of them gets out. The last part is that if two or more turtles bump into each other, they go two steps back towards the center. I have everything except that, and I'm not sure how to proceed. Below is the code I have so far. Can anyone help? Thanks!

```
from random import randrange
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def turtle1234():
    x_points = []
    y_points = []
    x2_points = []
    y2_points = []
    x3_points = []
    y3_points = []
    x4_points = []
    y4_points = []
    x = 0
    y = 0
    x2 = 0
    y2 = 0
    x3 = 0
    y3 = 0
    x4 = 0
    y4 = 0
    while True:
        x = x + randrange(-1,2)
        y = y + randrange(-1,2) 
        x2 = x2 + randrange(-1,2)
        y2 = y2 + randrange(-1,2) 
        x3 = x3 + randrange(-1,2)
        y3 = y3 + randrange(-1,2) 
        x4 = x4 + randrange(-1,2)
        y4 = y4 + randrange(-1,2) 
        x_points.append(x)
        y_points.append(y)
        x2_points.append(x2)
        y2_points.append(y2)
        x3_points.append(x3)
        y3_points.append(y3)
        x4_points.append(x4)
        y4_points.append(y4)
        if x**2+y**2 > 100**2:
            print(x,y)
            print('Turtle 1 is outside the circle first')
            break
        if x2**2+y2**2 > 100**2:
            print(x2,y2)
            print('Turtle 2 is outside the circle first')
            break
        if x3**2+y3**2 > 100**2:
            print(x3,y3)
            print('Turtle 3 is outside the circle first')
            break
        if x4**2+y4**2 > 100**2:
            print(x4,y4)
            print('Turtle 4 is outside the circle first')
            break
    plt.plot(x_points,y_points)
    plt.plot(x2_points,y2_points)
    plt.plot(x3_points,y3_points) 
    plt.plot(x4_points,y4_points) 
x = np.linspace(-100,100,1000)
turtle1234()


plt.plot(x,-np.sqrt(100**2-x**2), color = 'b')
plt.plot(x, np.sqrt(100**2-x**2), color = 'b')
```

Comment: What is your problem? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
turtles = [(x, y), (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3)]
for index, turtle1 in enumerate(turtles):
    for index2, turtle2 in enumerate(turtles):
        if index == index2:
            continue
        if turtle1 == turtle2:
            pass # go tow steps to the middle
```

Answer (score 0):

## This code should be put right after line 32#

```
    xkeys = [[x,y],[x2,y2],[x3,y3],[x4,y4]]
    for xy in xkeys:

        if xkeys.count(xy) >1:

            first = xkeys.index(xy)

            xkeys.reverse()
            second = (len(xkeys) - 1)-xkeys.index(xy)
            xkeys.reverse()

            
            for x in xkeys[first]:
                if x>=52:
                    xkeys[first][xkeys[first].index(x)]-=2
                if x<=48:
                    xkeys[first][xkeys[first].index(x)]+=2

            for x in xkeys[second]:
                if x>=52:
                    xkeys[second][xkeys[second].index(x)]-=2
                if x<=48:
                    xkeys[second][xkeys[second].index(x)]+=2
            break
    x = xkeys[0][0]
    y = xkeys[0][1] 
    x2 = xkeys[1][0]
    y2 = xkeys[1][1] 
    x3 = xkeys[2][0]
    y3 = xkeys[2][1] 
    x4 = xkeys[3][0]
    y4 = xkeys[3][1]
```

Here I made a nested list from the given movement values

```
    xkeys = [[x,y],[x2,y2],[x3,y3],[x4,y4]]
```

Then iterated through it with a condition that there are duplicates

```
    for xy in xkeys:
        if xkeys.count(xy) >1:
```

first is the index of the 1st duplicate inside the nested list

```
            first = xkeys.index(xy)
```

to get the 2nd i reversed the list as a spontaneous solution, assigned the 2nd duplicate index
then reversed the list again

```
            xkeys.reverse()
            second = (len(xkeys) - 1)-xkeys.index(xy)
            xkeys.reverse()
```

Here I made an assumption that the middle point is (50,50)

```
            for x in xkeys[first]:
                if x>=52:
                    xkeys[first][xkeys[first].index(x)]-=2
                if x<=48:
                    xkeys[first][xkeys[first].index(x)]+=2

            for x in xkeys[second]:
                if x>=52:
                    xkeys[second][xkeys[second].index(x)]-=2
                if x<=48:
                    xkeys[second][xkeys[second].index(x)]+=2
            break
```

Here I re-assigned the initial movement values based on their position in the
made nested list

```
    x = xkeys[0][0]
    y = xkeys[0][1] 
    x2 = xkeys[1][0]
    y2 = xkeys[1][1] 
    x3 = xkeys[2][0]
    y3 = xkeys[2][1] 
    x4 = xkeys[3][0]
    y4 = xkeys[3][1]
```